# Magento 2.3.1 add new extension installation issue

Tags: magento, ccavenue

we are facing install **new extension** and I get same issue in all extension when i am added in development url please help me out and thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fudI.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by changing the permissions of var folder and its subfolder to 777 by using

```
sudo chmod -R 777 *
```

Hope this will help someone new to **ubuntu** and **magento**

**OR**

Try to run the cron files of Magento by run the cron file separately.

```
php bin/magento cron:run

php update/cron.php

php bin/magento setup:cron:run
```

Comment: Hi Arpit First of all thanks for your reply 
I am hit all three command but I get the same issue any other suggestion from your end

Comment: what error you got please give me full error detail so that i can help you. also did you pass 777 permission

Comment: when I am hitting sudo command it was asking me the password I want to know that which password I want to enter password like my system or Cpanel

Comment: tell me one thing did you open it on ubuntu or your local window machine

Comment: in centeos i open in VPS server